# intelliJ 9 cannot find class I specify in web.xml

Tags: intellij-idea, classpath, slf4j

I am trying to get [logdigger](http://logdigger.com/logdigger-connector/java-logging-app-engine) to work in my java app that uses google app engine.  I have tried putting my jar files in the src/ directory, lib/ directory, and no matter what I do, it can't find the class.  The only thing that it finds is the com.google.appengine stuff.  I have tried messing with my dependencies and it's not working.  Has anyone done this before and gotten it to work?  I am not sure how to modify the classpath through intelliJ (however in the project settings I have the jars linked as a dependency under the modules section).

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to look at the artifacts for your project.  IntelliJ separates runtime assembly of WARs into the artifacts section.  Look and see that your WAR file is assembled properly.  I'm guessing that you don't put the contents of the /lib directory into the WEB-INF/lib of your WAR.  The compiled output ought to go into WEB-INF/classes.  All other output belongs in the root of the deployment.

Comment: hmm, I was missing the library in the artifacts section.  I added that.  How do I get it to put the classes into WEB-INF/classes?

Comment: set it as your compile output path